# Loop back to beginning of array when you reach the end

Tags: php, arrays

Okay, I Have an array and I want to loop through it every time you press a button. And when the array has made it to its last number it starts on 0 again.

So it starts on `0`, when I press the button it goes to `1` and when I press again it goes to `2`. Lets say it has a lenght of three, so when I press again it should go back to 0...

I just don't know I can do that. Can someone help out? It would be hugely appreciated!

This is what I tried so far:

```
$foo = array('bar', 'baz');
$foo = 0;
$foo++;
update($foo);
```

Ofcourse is this not working because `$foo` becomes `0` each time the page reloads...

Comment: Add some code and try to explain what you already tried.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the client. It can't do anything on button presses.

Comment: added some code, what I tried

Comment: Try sessions or work something out with `$_GET`

Comment: Yes, I tried...
But it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is quite simple. Just have a conditional statement that sets your loop variable back to 0 if it hits the length of the array. Here is some very basic pseudo code.

```
if(loopvariable = arrayLength){
  set loopVariable = 0
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand. :/

Comment: I am not that familiar with PHP but my recommendation was to use whatever conditional logic exists within PHP to create a small if else statement that essentially checks to see if the value of the looping variable is equal to the length of the array. If it is, set it back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it.
I just put the variables in an session.

This is my code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['b']))
    $_SESSION['b'] = 0;


$_SESSION['b'] += 1;
if($_SESSION['b'] > 4){
    $_SESSION['b'] = 0;
}
```